# Will Javascript read returned string as script or treat it as a string?

Tags: json, string, object

I am wondering is it possible to run a function that outputs a line that  javascript can read and recognize as a variable and not as a string? I have pulled JSON data and what I want to do is to take the object data and dynamically write out variables from it on the fly. I hope this is possible..

```js
function createVar(data){
   return "var_" + data.name + data.id + "=_" + data.desc;
   //This will return the line :
   var itemModel1 = "I no longer vote";
}
```

Comment: You can always call eval() on anything returned from your function. But depending on where the "data" comes from, this could be considered dangerous.

Comment: Thank you. I will try that first thing in the morning!

Answer (score -1):

I have to say that I don't really recommend this, but it does work.

```
function createVar(data){
   return "var " + data.name + data.id + "='" + data.desc + "'";
}

var exampleData = {name:"itemModel", id:"1", desc:"Today we went to the mall"}

eval(createVar(exampleData));

console.log(itemModel1); //outputs "Today we went to the mall" to the console
```

I will clarify by saying that if you actually need to generate variable names on the fly, this will do the trick. But I would more closely examine your code to see if there is another way to accomplish what you are trying to do. As always, you have to be very careful with eval, bad things can happen if user input gets passed as your data parameter.

Comment: If you don't recommend it why did you post it? What do you recommend?

Comment: I just answered his question with a result that works. Its hard to recommend anything better without more code. A starting point would be asking if and why generating variable names on the fly is actually necessary.

Comment: @FoxMulder900 - because what I am doing is pulling json data and then wanting to construct model instances from them to be used in backbone.js.

Comment: @Toshi - I see, why is it that you cannot create a model instance directly from the json? I'm not familiar with backbone specifically, but I would imagine you could pass your data directly into the models constructor.

Comment: @torazaburo - But if the variable is defined by calling this returned function, it would go out of scope immediately after it is created, making it inaccessible. Unless I am misunderstanding your suggestion.

Comment: Better to use json2's parse method, at least... safer and faster. https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js

Comment: @ FoxMulder ~ I am just experimenting... I want to create a function that will read the json data and then construct Backbone model instance from the data. In order to do this, I need to define it with this format  -----> var modelItem1 = new ModelItem({obj.desc});

Comment: @Toshi - I see, sounds interesting. Have fun ;)